# Unable to call a php page via Ajax for a button created using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a button in php and have used jquery + ajax to call another php page, but i am unable to call the php page for some reason. I have used tried two ways in jquery 1) using btn class and 2) using on click event, None of them seem to work

``PHP (to create button)

```
$functionname= "myCall(this.id);";
    $styleimage = "HEIGHT= 120  WIDTH= 120  BORDER= 0";
    $eventimage1= "zoomin(this)";
    $eventimage2= "zoomout(this)";
    $btnclass="btnclass";
    $btn= "btn".$category[$i];
            echo "<span id='" . $spa. "'>";
            echo "<button name='" . $btn. "'
            margin ='".$style."' 
            class='".$btnclass."'
            onClick='".$functionname."'
            >";
```

Jquery with button class name.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.btnclass').click(function() {

 event = event || window.event; 
var target = event.target || event.srcElement; 
var id = target.id;
var but = document.getElementById(id).parentNode.name;
alert (but);
var datastring = '&id='+ id;
alert (datastring);

$.ajax({
        url:  'indexverification.php',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: datastring,
        success: function(responseText) { // get the response
         if(responseText == 1) { alert ("hi");}
         else { alert (datastring); }
          window.location = 'indexverification.php'
        } // end success            
    });




});
```

});

Jquery  with event

```
function myCall(event) 
{
event = event || window.event; 
var target = event.target || event.srcElement; 
var id = target.id;
var but = document.getElementById(id).parentNode.name;
var datastring = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax({
                    url: "indexverification.php",
                    type: "POST",           
                    data: datastring,
                    success: function(responseText) { // get the response
                    if(responseText == 1) { alert("hi");}
                    else {  alert("hi"); }
                    }
                });
       }
```

indexverification.php

```
<?php
   $id=$_POST['id'];
   if (($id==$picno))
   {
       echo '1';
    }

    else 
   {
     echo '2';
   }
```

?>

Comment: what error do you get ? inspect network tab if request is happening or failing  !?

Comment: Don't know if, inline with the tag, `onclick` should be all lowercase. Also, that if statement within the indexverification.php will always fail because you're never starting the session in the file.

Comment: The on click part is working perfect, the problem arises after ajax. even if i remove the session it doesnt work.

Comment: I don't get any error.

Comment: @user3823853 what doesn't work? The code examples you provided aren't really concise or point out the problem. What are you expecting to occur that is not? "It doesn't work" is very abstract. The ajax request is not being called at all, the $_POST['id'] is not being sent to indexverification.php, the ajax success function is never triggered? For troubleshooting for an error you should add `error: function(jxhr, textStatus, error){ alert('An error occurred ' + textStatus + ' ' + error) }` to your ajax properties

Comment: I am not sure if its going to the php page as none of the alert messages seem to work on success. i tried using the error syntax but didnt get anything. nt even an alert dialog box

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the url. You are setting the url in you ajax as `indexverification.php`, so the url is relative to the current url. Let´s see, imagine you are in `www.mysite.com/page` so the url you are requesting is `www.mysite.com/page/indexverification.php`. Try to use url relative to the root like this `url:  '/indexverification.php'`, so you will always request the url `www.mysite.com/indexverification.php`, doesn't matter if you are in `www.mysite.com/page` or in `www.mysite.com` or `www.mysite.com/page2`.

Also, you need to check the url to the `indexverification.php` script. When you have the correct url you can set the url in your ajax request, and remember to set it relative to the root using `/` at the beginning of the url ;)